# How to filter preloaded has many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a `Post` model, and I wanted to show all of the posts to the current user together with the current user's comments.

Here's my current code.

```
Post.preload(:comments)
```

It will return all posts and its comments. How can I filter the comments to include only the current user's comments?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can create the scope:

```
scope :user_comments, -> (user) { includes(:comments).where(comments: { user: user }) }
```

And then

```
Post.user_comments(current_user)
```